# VeraCrypt installation error (Kubuntu 18.04) : Permission Denied

Tags: veracrypt

I'm trying to install Veracrypt (ver 1.22) using the gui and console installer downloaded from [Veracrypt's official website](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html), not from the PPA. I'm getting the following error when I click on the gui installer, or use 
     `sudo bash veracrypt-1.21-setup-gui-x64`

```
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good. 
Uncompressing VeraCrypt 1.22 Installer  100%  
/home/na/Downloads/veracrypt-1.22-setup-gui-x64: 1: eval: /veracrypt_install_gui_x64.sh: Permission denied
```

I've looked at the following resources: 
[Unable to install VeraCrypt - (k)ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976730/unable-to-install-veracrypt-kubuntu-17-10)
[VeraCrypt Gui Setup Problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004565/veracrypt-gui-setup-problem)
Discussions and Issues section in the codeplex [archives](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=veracrypt)

About my setup: Kubuntu (18.04), UEFI (Secure boot disabled), XTerm installed

The 'Permission' section for the gui installer is shown in the image:

[VeraCrypt gui installer permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRFB2.png)

I would really appreciate any help or suggestion. Thank you for your time.

---

Edit 1: Additional info: Not sure if this is relevant, but just in case: The installer works fine on my other machine (Kubuntu 16.04, MBR).  The error I'm getting is on a new Kubuntu 18.04 installation on a UEFI machine (secure boot disabled for NVIDIA issues). I tested the installer with Debian Stretch installed on a partition on the same machine (UEFI) - the installer gave the same error.

---

Edit #2: Here's a screenshot of what the output is when I try to install VeraCrypt (In this example, I'm using the built in console in Dolphin.)

[Screenshot - Veracrypt installation in Dolphin's console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1luaZ.png)

Comment: Author posted a comment saying *I have the latest VeraCrypt installer (version 1.22) and in my original post, typed 1.21 by mistake.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answering my own question] I am able to install VeraCrypt now.

**Diagnosis of the problem:** I had a tmpfs entry with 'noexec' option in /etc/fstab. The line in my fstab file read as:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777, 0 0
```

The VeraCrypt installer needs to use the tmp folder during the installation. The noexec option prevented it from doing so.

**What worked:** Removed the noexec option. The fstab entry was:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,mode=1777, 0 0
```

Remounted all filesystems (might require a reboot). I was then able to install VeraCrypt normally as before.

(Thanks to karel, pauljohn32 on AskUbuntu, and some great folks on the Debian IRC for their help.)

Answer (score 0):

I use veracrypt without trouble. Let's check the obvious first.

I wonder if sudo is not powerful enough here. Can you "su" to actually be root to try it? If you don't have root password set, I think "sudo -s" will launch a true root session. Problem may be that the Vera I installer wants to launch more shells.

As always, don't run things as root if you don't know for sure what your getting. But I have used Vera for a long time.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question: I tried "sudo -s", but got the same error.  (I don't have a separate root password or other user accounts on this setup.)

Comment: Can you paste in the transcript. Run "sudo -s" <hit return>. Then you are root. While there, you could set a root password.  There IS always a root account, part of the Ubuntu philosophy is to hide it from users.  Anyway,  then run "ls -la" to show us what directory your file is in, where you are.  Then run "sh .install_vera...".  Can you paste in the exact output?

Comment: Or don't try the GUI installer, use the console.  I just downloaded the installers you try and they want to uninstall my existing Vera and I don't want to do that right now.  So I cannot test this for you.

Comment: I tried the console installer, but it didn't work. Here's the output:                                                   `root@[hostname]:~/Downloads# ./veracrypt-1.22-setup-console-x64
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good.
Uncompressing VeraCrypt 1.22 Installer  100%  
./veracrypt-1.22-setup-console-x64: 1: eval: ./veracrypt_install_console_x64.sh: Permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

<s>There is some ambiguity in your question about whether you downloaded the latest version of VeraCrypt 1.22 or VeraCrypt 1.21.</s> user854153 downloaded veracrypt-1.22-setup-gui-x64. The following instructions are for VeraCrypt 1.22, the latest version because that's the version that shows on the screenshot.

1. Change directories using `cd` to the directory containing the veracrypt-1.22-setup-gui-x64 file and run the following command:

   ```
   ./veracrypt-1.22-setup-gui-x64
   ```
2. This command will bring up an xmessage VeraCrypt graphical installer window. Click the *Install VeraCrypt* button.

   [image]
3. Accept the VeraCrypt license terms by clicking the *I accept...* button.
4. Click the *OK* button.
5. Then enter your sudo password in the XTerm (VeraCrypt Setup) window.
6. After the installation is finished you can launch VeraCrypt by clicking on its icon.

Comment: Thanks replying to my question.  I apologise for the confusing typo. I have the latest installer (ver 1.22) and in my original post, typed 1.21 by mistake.  But I was typing the correct command (referring to version 1.22) in the console, after cd'ing into the correct directory. Still, in the past, clicking on the gui installer normally led to to the message you have in your response.